# The easiest way to set focus on single textBox upon onload

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Based on this link: [Set the focus on a textbox in xaml wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872238/set-the-focus-on-a-textbox-in-xaml-wpf) , `Focus` can be set by setting `FocusManager` at the `StackPanel` and specifying the elementName. I did tried out and it works. I'm wondering what if I have only one textbox in my `XAML` and `StackPanel` is unnecessary?

**Is there any other simple way to set focus given the scenario I only have one textbox?**

I've also tried the second answer in the above link but doesn't work:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyText}" 
    FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this in the past by putting the focus in the header - in this case a user control, though should be the same for a window)

```
<UserControl .....
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=TextBoxName}">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyText}" 
       FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBox}}"/>
```

or

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTBox" Text="{Binding MyText}" 
       FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=MyTBox}"/>
```

This will works for your case.