# Set focus on text box when item added to Listbox from C# Code in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I use following code for adding textbox as listbox item to the listbox:

```
TextBox sText = new TextBox();
sText.Template = FindResource("TextBoxControlTemplate") as ControlTemplate;
sText.Text = "hi";
LBATIModelsData.Items.Add(sText);
```

So, how put focus on the Textbox after adding to the listbox?

tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

`FocusManager.SetFocusedElement`

```
FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(LBATIModelsData, sText)
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1345413/461561) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2872306/461561) SO answers

Comment: and how can I set cursor on the textbox? after adding an item, its work very nice but first user must clicking on the textbox before push any key on the keyboard.

Comment: Try FocusManager.SetFocusedElement("Name of main grid", sText) .

Comment: It doesn't put cursor on the textbox!