# wpf how to auto focus on textBox filed

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I mark textBox as a default focus ?

When the windows is start , when the user press something it will be write on this textbox

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set the focus on a textbox in xaml wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872238/set-the-focus-on-a-textbox-in-xaml-wpf)

Answer (score 3):

Bind the `FocusManager.FocusedElement` attached property of the root panel to the `TextBox`:

```
<StackPanel FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=tb}">
    <TextBox x:Name="tb" Background="Beige" Text="..."/>
</StackPanel>
```

This will will work if you have a single focus scope, or if the focus scope to which the `TextBox` belongs currently has keyboard focus.

You could also use the `Keyboard.Focus` method to set the keyboard focus:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += (s, e) => Keyboard.Focus(tb);
}
}
```

There can be only one element on the whole desktop that has keyboard focus. Please refer to MSDN for more information.

**Focus Overview:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/focus-overview