# How To Enter A TextBox On Click

Tags: c#, xaml

Im trying to create a basic example sign up page.

I want the mouse pointer to enter the textbox only on click however it seems to enter the first textbox by default. What is the process to change this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817610/wpf-and-initial-focus

Comment: Set the focus to other control.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the opacity and sets it to 0 together with the IsEnabled attribute which I would set to false.

Then you put in your click event this simple code.
textbox.Opacity="1";
textbox.IsEnabled="true";

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Kenny Seemed To Work!

Comment: No problem! Glad that I could help you. It's something which I use when I want to hide stuff or to show it.

Comment: however i was intending to something different so i just shifted the order of the text box on the grid

Righ Click - Order - Send Back

That seemed to take away the focus on its own ;-)