# WPF data bindings being broken by FocusManager - WHY?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I've spent the last several days tracking down this bug.  My bindings were being detached, and I had no idea why.  I want one of my textboxes to have focus when my application starts.  So I used an attached property that sets the focused element.  Some of my data bindings stopped working.

For some reason, simply re-arranging my XAML caused the bug to go away.

Take this example:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Tb1}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Tb2}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Tb3}" 
           FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Tb4}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The bindings for Tb1, Tb2 and Tb3 all work.  **The Tb4 binding is broken.**  If I swap the last two lines, like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Tb1}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Tb2}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Tb4}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Tb3}" 
           FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

then all the bindings work just fine.

For some reason, **setting the focused element in XAML causes all bindings that come after it to break.**

Has anyone else seen this?  If so, do you know why this happens?

Comment: Does the binding produce an error in the output pane during debug, or does it just not work?

Comment: Nope.  During this whole process I wanted to make sure I didn't have any binding errors.  I've been using a trace listener in case I miss something in the output.  No errors were ever shown.  The binding just doesn't work.

Comment: When you say 'all bindings that come after it', do you mean all bindings in the StackPanel, or *all bindings* including those outwith the StackPanel?

Comment: I created another stackpanel after the one shown, and the textbox inside it also was not bound.

Comment: I couldn't say with absolute certainty, but I suspect that focusing on an element before the page is fully drawn may be interfering with the drawing process. To debug it I'd suggest naming your TextBox, then adding a Loaded event handler to the Window (or UserControl, or whatever hosts your controls), then focusing on your TextBox using MyTextBox.Focus() (per example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743469%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If that works then the issue is FocusManager interrupting the drawing/binding process.

Comment: I'm using MVVM, so that example unfortunately doesn't apply unless I want to break the pattern.

Comment: That example would be fine under MVVM - Focus has nothing to do with your business objects/is entirely a UI concern. Per the comment - '*to debug it*' - try the above out and see what happens. If it works then you've identified the problem.

Comment: Yes, setting the focus on the object from my viewmodel does fix the problem.  This is what I suspected.  Now that we've confirmed that FocusManager is breaking the bindings in the XAML, my question is WHY?  I found a related article but it's specifically related to command bindings being broken, and it still doesn't really make sense.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f5de6ffc-fa03-4f08-87e9-77bbad752033/a-focusscope-nightmare-bug-commands-are-disabled?forum=wpf

Comment: I think I'm inching towards an answer. Are your controls in a Window, or in a UserControl?

Comment: In a window.  My view model is being set as the datacontext for a window where the XAML is defined in a datatemplate.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way to use `FocusManager.FocusedElement` is to set the attached property on an element higher in the visual tree:

```
<StackPanel FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=firstButton}">
  <Button Name="firstButton" />
</StackPanel>
```

Maybe setting the attached property on the element itself is not well supported.