# WPF MVVM disable focus on ContentControl (with the Tab key)

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a window with a `ContentControl` binding:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />
```

I also have an empty user control binds to the `ContentControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

When I run and press the tab keyboard I get a dotted rectangle around the content control. How can I disable this?

I tried using `Focusable="False"` and `FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"` without success...

Comment: Is the user control used somewhere?  This seems irrelevant.  When using Focusable="False" in the ContentControl it won't take the dotted rectangle.  You might need to show more of your code to clear it up.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting IsTabStop="False", for example...

```
<ContentControl Height="200" Width="200" IsTabStop="False">
    <ContentControl.Content>
        <TextBox/>
    </ContentControl.Content>
</ContentControl>
```

and I would suggest you combine it with this trick:

```
Loaded += (sender, e) =>
MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```

from the answer to this question: [WPF and initial focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817610/wpf-and-initial-focus)

Comment: Setting IsTabStop=False on the ContentControl works great to prevent it from getting focus from Tab keys. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Override the ContentControl Style and add property FocusVisualStyle as null and implement by using style property

```
<ContentControl Height="200" Width="200" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">
            <ContentControl.Content>
                <local:UserControl1/>
            </ContentControl.Content>
       </ContentControl>
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: I have added a sample of code or your reference. just add FocusVisualStyle as null in your contentcontrol its enough

Comment: This just removes the visual, you still have to press Tab twice to get off the ContentControl