# How to set tab order?

Tags: wpf, .net-core

I've three Classes in my project `Master`, `Person` and `Command`. `Master` has two properties, a constructor and overridden the `ToString`:

```
class Master {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Master(string FirstName, string LastName) {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }
}
```

`Command` is an implementation of `ICommand`

```
class Command : ICommand {
    Func<object, bool> CanDo { get; set; }
    Action<object> Do { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public Command(Func<object, bool> CanDo, Action<object> Do) {
        this.CanDo = CanDo;
        this.Do = Do;
        CommandManager.RequerySuggested += (o, e) => Evaluate();
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => CanDo(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => Do(parameter);
    public void Evaluate() => CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

and `Person` has two properties, implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`, is an `ObservableCollection<Master>` and using `Command`:

```
class Person : ObservableCollection<Master>, INotifyPropertyChanged {

    string firstName, lastName;

    public string FirstName {
        get => firstName;
        set { firstName = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public string LastName {
        get => lastName;
        set { lastName = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public Command AddToList { get; set; }
    public new event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Person() {
        AddToList = new Command(CanDo, Do);
    }

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "") => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));        
    bool CanDo(object para) => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName);
    void Do(object para) {
        Add(new Master(firstName, firstName));
        FirstName = LastName = null;
    }
}
```

On xaml I've these:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:Person x:Key="Person"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource Person}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
            <Button Content="Click" Command="{Binding AddToList}"/>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I've to click on the first `TextBox`, bound to `FirstName`, after launching the app to type something there, by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> I can type in the second `TextBox` and if I then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again, it instead of focusing the `Button` goes back to first `TextBox` so I've to hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice to get to the `Button` and by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> I can add the item in the `ListView`.

At this point I'm not sure what's focused, I've to hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> once more to get to the first `TextBox`. After typing some more text in first as well as second `TextBoxes` if I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it instead of focusing `Button` or first `TextBox` selects the `ListView` so I've to hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> thrice to get to the `Button`!

I want to give first `TextBox` focus when the app launches and after hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> on second `TextBox` I want it to go to the `Button` and exclude `ListView` from focus. I've tried setting `Focusable="False"`, `KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"`, `IsTabStop="False"` in `ListView` but those don't work! I also have tried setting`TabIndex` on `TextBoxes` and `Button` like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}" TabIndex="1"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}" TabIndex="2"/>
<Button Content="Click" Command="{Binding AddToList}" TabIndex="3"/>
```

These don't work either!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is that at the point you tab away from the second text box it needs to decide where to place the focus. However, at that point in time, the command is still disabled because it cannot be executed because the value from the text box has not arrived in the view model yet. This value arrives after the focus has been moved.

One way to fix this would be to change the binding of the second textbox so that the ViewModel is updated on every change to the value. Add the following clause to that binding:

```
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
```

More details here... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-control-when-the-textbox-text-updates-the-source

Now whenever you type a character the command will reconsider whether it can be executed.

Comment: great! when the app launches it still doesn't focus the first `TextBox` and when I hit `space` or `enter` on `Button` it doesn't go back to first `TextBox`, I've to hit tab to take it back to the first box.

Comment: The initial focus issue is a bizarre 'feature' of WPF see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817610/wpf-and-initial-focus for a fix for that.

Comment: And to see where the focus is going after the button, try using a WPF developer support app like Snoop or WpfInspector. If you keep tabbing, it will come back around. You just need to find where it went and make sure that can't receive the focus.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer:

Set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on your binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I suspect what is happening is that WPF is evaluating the next tab position before the command CanExecute is evaluated, so when it is working out where to tab to next the button is still disabled, hence the only place it has to go is back to the first text box.

UpdateSourceTrigger tells WPF to evaluate the bindings on each keypress instead of when the focus changes, which means the button is correctly enabled by the time it needs to work the tab stops out.

Comment: For the first time I've to click on the first box and after hitting space on button I've to tab again to go to first box.