# ListView isn't working properly with ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, .net-core

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58367639/how-to-set-tab-order) the code I'm working with. In `xaml` I've expanded the `ListView` like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="lv" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
       <ListView.InputBindings>
           <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding Edit}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lv}"/>
           <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding Edit}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lv}"/>
       </ListView.InputBindings>
</ListView>
```

and implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `Master` class to see updates in `ListView` when I edit an item. In `Person` class I've added one more `Command`

```
public Command Edit { get; set; }
```

intialized it in constructior:

```
Edit = new Command(CanClick, EditItem);
```

and implemented those callbacks like this:

```
bool CanClick(object arg) => Count > 0;
void EditItem(object obj) {
    if(obj != null{
        var item = obj as Master;
        item.FirstName = "Edited";
        item.LastName = "Edited";
        SetItem(IndexOf(item), item);
    }
}
```

When I select an item and hit <kbd>Return</kbd> it updates the collection BUT I don't see any change in `ListView`. If I double click on an item, it neither updates the collection nor the `ListView`!

Another question is why do I have to set a name for the `ListView` to use in nested `InputBindings` like this `ElementName=lv`? Can I get rid of that?

---

**EDIT**

---

If I expand the `ListView` further like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="lv" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
     <ListView.View>
         <GridView>
             <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" Width="200" 
                 DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
             <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" Width="200" 
                 DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" />
         </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
     <ListView.InputBindings>
         <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding Edit}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lv}"/>
         <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding Edit}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lv}"/>
     </ListView.InputBindings>
 </ListView>
```

`ListView` reflects the update I make through `void EditItem(object obj)` BUT `MouseBinding` doesn't work in this way either. Why would one bind individual property like this for a collection?

Comment: Your collection should also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: Person is an observablecollection of master? This is a very strange way to work. Much more usual to have a viewmodel set as datacontext. That would have an observablecollection of person viewmodels. All viewmodels implement inotifypropertychanged. Bind selecteditem to another property of the viewmodel. Then your command can work with that selected item.

Comment: As Andy describes: You should also implemente INotifyPropertyChanged to the Person class.

Comment: @Andy, that's what it is I think: `Person` is in `DataContext`, it is an `ObservableCollection<Master>` and both `Person` and `Master` implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`. When I hit `Return` after selecting an item, `void EditItem(object obj)` gets the `SelectedItem`.

Comment: @EmonHaque: What does "updates the collection BUT I don't see any change in ListView" mean exactly?

Comment: @mm8, if I launch the app in debug mode  after setting a breakpoint at the end of `EditItem` method, select an item in the `ListView` and hit `Return`. `this` pointer in `Autos` window shows the updated list BUT the `ListView` doesn't reflect the change!

Comment: @EmonHaque: Why are you calling `SetItem`?

Comment: @mm8, isn't it for editing an item in the list?

Comment: You edit an item by setting its properties and implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Does `Master` implement this interface?

Comment: @mm8, it works this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to call `SetItem` to update an item.

Setting the properties is enough provided that the `Master` class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` correctly.

When it comes to handling double-clicks, you could add a reference to [System.Windows.Interactivity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/) and use an `EventTrigger`:

```
<ListView x:Name="lv" ItemsSource="{Binding}" xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Edit}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lv}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: that's right, I actually don't need that BUT mousebinding doesn't work. If I don't bind individual properties like I did in EDIT part, listview doesn't reflect the change.

Comment: @EmonHaque: See my edit about using an `EventTrigger` to handle double-clicks.

Comment: lol, to avoid the blend iteractivity triggers I'd added `Xaml.Behaviors` nuget package to make it simpler! looks like it still is a must to use blend interactivity for this! Doubleclick works when I click on the borders of `ListView`, there's a small margin/padding around the list in listview, it triggers when I double click on that blank area!

Comment: It triggers when the `ListView` raises the `MouseDoubleClick` event as you would expect.

Comment: I'd expect the same event to be raised when I doubleclick on a listitem in the ListView. KeyBinding does what is expected BUT the MouseBinding doesn't!

Comment: @EmonHaque: So use an event trigger.

Comment: Yes, that's probably the only option for now! Hope the devs will fix the mousebinding soon