# TabControl switches Tabs automatically because Button remains it's focus

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following `TabControl`:

```
<TabControl x:Name="Tabs">
  <TabItem x:Name="TabItem1" Header="TabItem1" />
  <TabItem x:Name="TabItem2" Header="TabItem2" />
</TabControl>
```

`TabItem1` has a ToolBar with some buttons inside. `TabItem2` doesn't have a toolbar.

Since upgrading .NET version from 4.6.1 to 4.8 I encounter the following behaviour:

1. When `TabItem1` is being selected by the user the first button inside the toolbar gets focus.
2. When the user now selects `TabItem2` it *sometimes switches back to `TabItem1`*. This seems to be because the first button in `TabItem1` remains it's focus.

Why didn't this happen with .NET 4.6.1? Is there any way to avoid this issue?

Comment: Quite related, and including a work-around suggestion(s), "WPF and Initial Focus": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817610/wpf-and-initial-focus

Comment: Hm but there the opposite problem is discussed: nothing gets focus. My problem is that the first button gets focus which seems to case the tab being switched back again.

Comment: So that - as a guess - it could possibly help if (a control inside) `TabItem2` would take the focus away from that TabItem1 Button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround by using a global event handler for all `TabItem`s. On event the first control in the `TabItem` (which is usually the header) is being focused.

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
  EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TabItem), Selector.SelectedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(TabItem_Selected));
}

private void TabItem_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  TabItem item = e.Source as TabItem;
  item?.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
}
```

But I still wonder why I do encounter this weird behaviour ... it shouldn't be necessary at all to use this workaround.